# How do I update my build.gradle file to update the current Spring version?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-security

Here's my current build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "5.0.1"
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.3"
    id 'jacoco'
}

group = 'XXX.XXXX.XXX'
version = '1.1.0'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://XXXXXXXX.XXXX.XXX/XXXXXXXX/repo'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

war {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.17.1'
    
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.1.3'
    
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2"
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: '*.jar')
    
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    
        testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.7.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console-standalone:1.9.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
       ignoreFailures = true
          finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

  jacocoTestReport {
        dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report
        
     reports {
    xml.enabled true
    html.enabled true
    xml.destination = file(getBuildDir().toString() + File.separator.toString() + "jacoco" + File.separator.toString() + "coverage.xml")
    csv.enabled false
    html.destination = file(getBuildDir().toString() + File.separator.toString() + "jacoco" + File.separator.toString() + "html")
  }
    }
```

I tried changing the version numbers and modifying the plugin numbers or the dependencies, but I'm unsure on where or what to change. I'm trying to update the spring version either by using Eclipse or changing the build.gradle number manually. How do I update the build.gradle file to use a new Spring version - spring-security-core-5.3.4.RELEASE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the `org.springframework.boot` because you use spring boot, in your case you have `2.3.4R` i recommend you to migrate in 2 steps.

First one: change version to `2.7.8` that work great with jdk 8 that you use, here you will have some changes in openapi(recommendation sprinfox(swagger2) with opendoc-api [migration-guide](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html), because *Springfox is deprecated for removal in version 7.0. 0 of openapi-generator. The project seems to be no longer maintained (last commit is of Oct 14, 2020). It works with Spring Boot 2.5.*)
Also some problems can appear with dependency injections you should fix it) and that's all i think.

Second stept: from `2.7.8 to 3.1.x` here is more interesting you should have jdk 17 also you will have migraion to newest java version, you can find more articles about how to do it, about spring-boot [Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide)